# Failed to query Azure Cosmos Db Emulator via mongoose

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am new to Cosmos Db. I got null when I tried to query Azure Cosmos db emulator by mongoose. But if I query the Cosmos Db hosted on Azure, everything work fine. I don't known what's wrong with my code.  Any idea what the problem could be and how to workaround this

[image]

Here is my code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        "id": String,
        "status": String,
        "owner": String,
        "sn": String
    }

);
schema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true,
    transform: (doc, ret, options) => {
        delete ret.__v;
        delete ret._id;
    },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('projects', schema);
```

---

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:10255/picassoData?ssl=true',  
    { 
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        auth: {
            user: "localhost",
            password: "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw=="
          }
    });

var Projects = require('./project');
var x = await Projects.findOne({id: "123"}).exec();
```

Comment: Try changing the database name (in your connection string) from `picassoData` to `admin` to see if you can connect.